# Save Edit destroys the Sketch Tool

Tags: arcobjects, editing, arcgis-10.3

I have edit tool(s) in ArcObjects (ArcGIS10.3). 
The first tool is "Create a new Polygon' and following is the code:

Note: mpEditor is class member and Project is in Edit Mode

```
private void StartCreatePolygon()
{
 IEditTaskSearch pEditTaskSearch;
 IEditTask pEditTask;

  pEditTaskSearch = (IEditTaskSearch)mpEditor;
  pEditTask =     pEditTaskSearch.get_TaskByUniqueName("GarciaUI_CreateNewFeatureTask");

 if (pEditTask != null)
 {
   mpEditor.CurrentTask = pEditTask;
   SelectSketchTool();
 }
}

private void SelectSketchTool()
{
   //'Selects the default sketch tool
   UID pID = new UID();
   ICommandBars pCommandBars = mpApp.Document.CommandBars;
   ICommandItem pCommandItem;
   pID.Value = "esriEditor.SketchTool";
   pCommandItem = pCommandBars.Find(pID);
   if (pCommandItem != null)
   {
     pCommandItem.Execute();
   }
}
```

PROBLEM: When I finish Crating a new polygon and press "Save Edits" on the ArcGIS Edit tool bar, the 'esriEditor.SketchTool' disappears and normal 'Arrow' icon is activated.

Please help me that after save I keep the Sketch Tool ON.